# "__(" in custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building my custom post types for a wordpress project, but I do not understand why in some examples over the internet it's possbile to find something like this:

```
register_post_type('omb_prodotti',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'customposttype' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'customposttype' )
      )
```

what is "__(" used for? Is it related to translations? Wouldn't it be possible to just write it like this instead:

```
register_post_type('omb_prodotti',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'customposttype',
        'singular_name' => 'customposttype'
      )
```

Sorry but I'm a beginner in both PHP and building custom WP themes.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @cale_b thanks, I retracted the close vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to search for `__` in a search engine but with `wordpress double underscore` I found the answer in WordPress documentation:

> #### Description
>
> Retrieves the translated string from the translate().
>
> #### Usage
>
> `<?php $translated_text = __( $text, $domain ); ?>`

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2).

As you wrote, this is a function to translate content. About your question, if you don't call the `__()` function the string won't be translated, it will only display `customposttype`. With `__('customposttype')`, it will load a translation instead, which is probably a relevant string. You have to look at the code to find the corresponding string.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the WP documentation for this exactly, you may have a hard time finding it - unless you have an idea of what it's for, which is [i18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

There you will discover that this function is used for Internationalization (aka i18n), or translation of strings into other languages.

It depends on what you'll be using your code for - if it's not something you will ever distribute to others to use, then you don't really need to worry about it.

However, if it's a plugin that you will publish and others will use, then you do in fact need to understand how to use it.

There's four functions in WP that do this:

```
// Returns the translated string
__('My String to Translate', 'mytextdomain');

// Echos the translated string
_e('My String to Translate', 'mytextdomain');

// Returns the translated string, using different translations based on "domain"
_x('My String to Translate', 'mytextdomain', 'domain');

// Echos the translated string, using different translations based on "domain"

_ex('My String to Translate', 'mytextdomain');
```

Note that the translation is not "Automatic" - it's read from a file provided by the theme or plugin (and someone has to manually create / translate each of those strings).

This article is quite useful: http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/